# Can I get the failed request id when PhantomJS get resource error?

Tags: phantomjs

I don't quite understand why PhantomJS only returns the url of request for [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) callback, while for the other [two resource callbacks](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html) it returns the request id. That makes "finding which request did actually fail" really impossible if there is more than one request to the same url. Does anyone knows how to get the failed request id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that's just old documentation. `onResourceError` has the id of a failed request.

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.log('Unable to load resource (request ID:' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);

};
```

Comment: Really? I have just tried that, it seems not getting the id. Which version of PhantomJs are you using? I'm using 1.9.0.

Comment: Tried with 1.9.1, could get the id now! Awesome work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you really need to request id ?

Since `onResourceError` was added in 1.9, some information may be missing.

A way to resolve your problem is to keep in an array all requested resourcessuach as in  [netsniff](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.js) example.
Here is a very basic implementation :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system');


if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netsniff.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {

    page.address = system.args[1];
    page.resources = [];

    page.onLoadStarted = function () {
        page.startTime = new Date();
    };

    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        page.resources[req.id] = {
            request: req,
            startReply: null,
            endReply: null
        };
    };

    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        if (res.stage === 'start') {
            page.resources[res.id].startReply = res;
        }
        if (res.stage === 'end') {
            page.resources[res.id].endReply = res;
        }
    };

    page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.log('Unable to load resource (URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);

    page.resources.forEach(function (resource) {
    var request = resource.request,
            endReply = resource.endReply;

        if (request && request.url === resourceError.url && !endReply) {
            console.log('request id was :' + request.id);
        }
    })

};


    page.open(page.address, function (status) {
        var har;
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
            page.endTime = new Date();
            page.title = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.title;
            });
            console.log(page.title);
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
}
```

`onResourceError`, you just need to find first/last/all recorded urls that match the error resource url.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing the same way, recording all requests and their id. But my issue is there could be more than one requests pointing to the same url, some have error, some don't. In that case, it is hard to tell which one is failed.